# Can't use jquery ajax to reorder a list

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm using jquery ajax to load a new php query where the list order is changed. But for some reason, nothing happens. This is the query I'm using (load.php):

```
$stm = $conn->prepare('SELECT projetos.projeto FROM projetos ORDER BY projetos.projeto DESC');
$stm->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

echo json_encode($result);
```

And this is an excerpt from jquery:

```
$('.chosen-select').change( function(){

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',  
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'php/load.php',
    success: function(data) {
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
          $('#project-grid').append(data[i].projeto)
        }
   } 
});

});
```

Comment: What do you see when you console.log(data) within your success function?

Comment: @meavo I add an error function and return the following: Undefined variable: stmt in ...load.php on line 9

Comment: inspect the request in network tab of browser console/ developer tools  for clues...can see what is sent, what is returned, status etc

Comment: Stupid mistake: $stm and $stmt. Sorry guys.

Comment: @user3004794 I was just suggesting you might have a typo somewhere lol :)

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a GET request instead of a POST:

```
$.get('php/load.php', function (data) 
{
   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
   {
    $('#project-grid').append(data[i].projeto)
   }
});
```